# C# - Trying to grab and save a pdf into my database

Tags: c#, file, pdf, stream, filestream

In my C# application, I am trying to make it able to pull a pdf and save it, so that end users can press a button and pull up that pdf while they are in the application. But when I copy the content to the filestream it makes the pdf but it is just blank with nothing from the original pdf. What am I doing wrong?

The pdf's could also have pictures on them, and I don't think the way I'm doing it would allow those to be brought over.

```
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

bool? response = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();

var fileContent = string.Empty;

var filestream = openFileDialog.OpenFile();

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filestream))
{
    fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

// make folder path
string FolderPath = "ProjectPDFs\\";  

string RootPath = "X:\\Vents-US Inventory";

DirectoryInfo FolderDir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(RootPath, FolderPath));

Directory.CreateDirectory(FolderDir.ToString());

string filePath = "";

string FileName = openFileDialog.SafeFileName;

if (fileContent.Length > 0)
{
    filePath = Path.Combine(FolderDir.ToString(), FileName);
    using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        byte[] bytestream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileContent);

        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(bytestream);

        stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: The following may be of interest: [File.ReadAllBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes?view=net-7.0) and [OpenFileDialog Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

Comment: @KJ so should I make it like this?                                                                                                               
 byte[] bytestream = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileContent);